# ERROR: cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character' with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I am attempting to leverage ggplot code found on SO.  The problem is i keep getting errors and i think it has something to do with trying to pass the the functions through shinydashboard.  I've tried all sorts of things.  I can get this to render fine in the console but not in shinydashboard.

```
 library(shinydashboard)
 library(shiny)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(dplyr)

 ui <- fluidPage(
   gggauge(52,breaks=c(0,35,70,100)
 )

 )
 server <- function(input, output) {
   gggauge <- function(pos,breaks=c(0,30,70,100)) {
     get.poly <- function(a,b,r1=0.5,r2=1.0) {
       th.start <- pi*(1-a/100)
       th.end <- pi*(1-b/100)
       th <- seq(th.start,th.end,length=100)
       x <- c(r1*cos(th),rev(r2*cos(th)))
       y <- c(r1*sin(th),rev(r2*sin(th)))
       return(data.frame(x,y))
     }
     ggplot()+ 
      geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[1],breaks[2]),aes(x,y),fill="red")+
      geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[2],breaks[3]),aes(x,y),fill="gold")+geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[3],breaks[4]),aes(x,y),fill="forestgreen")+
      geom_polygon(data=get.poly(pos-1,pos+1,0.2),aes(x,y))+
      geom_text(data=as.data.frame(breaks), size=5, fontface="bold", vjust=0,
        aes(x=1.1*cos(pi*(1-breaks/100)),y=1.1*sin(pi*(1-breaks/100)),label=paste0(breaks,"%")))+
      annotate("text",x=0,y=0,label=pos,vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
      coord_fixed()+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank()) 
   }
 }
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

gggauge <- function(pos,breaks=c(0,30,70,100)) {
  get.poly <- function(a,b,r1=0.5,r2=1.0) {
    th.start <- pi*(1-a/100)
    th.end <- pi*(1-b/100)
    th <- seq(th.start,th.end,length=100)
    x <- c(r1*cos(th),rev(r2*cos(th)))
    y <- c(r1*sin(th),rev(r2*sin(th)))
    return(data.frame(x,y))
  }
  ggplot()+ 
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[1],breaks[2]),aes(x,y),fill="red")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[2],breaks[3]),aes(x,y),fill="gold")+geom_polygon(data=get.poly(breaks[3],breaks[4]),aes(x,y),fill="forestgreen")+
    geom_polygon(data=get.poly(pos-1,pos+1,0.2),aes(x,y))+
    geom_text(data=as.data.frame(breaks), size=5, fontface="bold", vjust=0,
              aes(x=1.1*cos(pi*(1-breaks/100)),y=1.1*sin(pi*(1-breaks/100)),label=paste0(breaks,"%")))+
    annotate("text",x=0,y=0,label=pos,vjust=0,size=8,fontface="bold")+
    coord_fixed()+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text=element_blank(),
          axis.title=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          panel.grid=element_blank(),
          panel.border=element_blank()) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    #plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
    gggauge(52,breaks=c(0,35,70,100))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Output**

[image]

**Explanation**

You mixed up a few things but you were *almost* there. Everything you need is right here. You just need to organize. Let's go through the components -

1. `gggauge` is a function that renders the plot, so it needs to be a function defined separately and *called* from the server component. Merely defining it in the `server` object was not enough. In your case the function was getting defined, not called!
2. The `ui` component needs a placeholder for rendering a plot. Directly trying to render the plot in `ui` won't cut it. You just need an `plotOutput` object there which acts as a placeholder (a UI component)
3. Now that (1) and (2) are taken care of, its time to render the plot in the `server` object by calling the `gggauge` function.

Hop that helps!

Comment: really appreciate the teaching feedback.  This structure did the trick and i have a better understanding...simple question i think...why does this function need to be declared outside of server code compared to other functions?

Comment: @Basballguy just good coding practice to keep it modular. When you will develop more complex apps the server, UI and global files with sit in different script files. Just makes more design sense thats it!